# Disable all parent htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, web-hosting

I have wordpress installed in the root of my website public_html

Although I have other folder inside a projects folder running their own websites.

The .htaccess in the wordpress folder (parent-most folder) might be causing issues for the inside folders.

Is there a way, I can mention for a folder not to look any higher for htaccess files ?

DETAIL:

The two main issues I am currently having our
- if I set the status code to 500, I am get redirected to my home page (index.php)
- if a page is not found, it gets redirected to index.php

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory (just above your wordpress rewrite stuff):

```
RewriteRule ^subfolder(/.*|)$ - [L]
```

Comment: Could you explain what that does ?

Comment: Does it not include the rules for the folder "subfolder" ?

Comment: It just means that DO NOT do any redirect for any URI that looks like  `www.domain.com/subfolder/*`

Comment: Great to know it worked out, Please consider accepting the answer whenever you can.